# Caching cloud endpoint responses in Android client

Tags: android, caching, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a ListView which gets populated with data retrieved from a cloud endpoint.

Every time this screen pops up, the list gets fetched from the server. But I want it to use cached responses when it haven't been too long since the last update.

Is there anyway I can do this easily using the default `Api.Builder` ?